# SonarCloud: How To Use T-SQL rules instead of PL/SQL rules

Tags: sonarqube-scan, sonarcloud

I have c# code and Database projects in the repo that I am getting scanned on SonarQube.

However, the SQL scripts are scanned using the PL/SQL rule set rather than the T-SQL rule set.

Is there a setting to tell Sonar to do it in an expected way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same problem, and it turns out you can configure this on the **General Settings** > **Languages** page.

If you select **PL/SQL** from the dropdown, you'll see the file suffix ".sql" in the list. Delete it, and click Save.
Then select **T-SQL** from the dropdown, and add the file suffix ".sql" and click Save.

Now your .SQL files will be analyzed as regular T-SQL.

[image]